# Upright font in glossary of mathematical symbols using the glossaries package

Tags: math-mode, symbols, glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package to create a glossary of mathematical symbols, but I can't get it to work with upright text in the symbols. I have tried using both `\mathrm` and `\textup`. It only seems to cause problems if there are two or more definitions that use upright text. Here is a MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries


\newglossaryentry{x}
{
name={$\mathrm{x}$},
description={description},
}

\newglossaryentry{y}
{
name={$\mathrm{y}$},
description={description},
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
\gls{x}
\gls{y}


\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

The result is a whole heap of `Undefined control sequence` errors, as well as one `Too many }'s` error. It works fine if I remove one of the definitions (and its reference), or if I remove at least one of the `\mathrm` commands.

Is there a way to get math-mode, upright text to work nicely with `glossaries`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine if you use `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries` rather than the `noidx` versions:

[image: glossaries with upright maths]

In this case, you must use either `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite` to generate the glossary list. The latter is more limited but does not require Perl and seems to work fine here.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{x}
{
  name={$\mathrm{x}$},
  description={description},
}
\newglossaryentry{y}
{
  name={$\mathrm{y}$},
  description={description},
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
\gls{x}
\gls{y}

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay. I can't get either of them to work. I've installed Perl and set TexnicCenter to run makeindex.bat in the output profile, but the above mwe Still doesn't work; no errors and no warnings, but no glossary produced either. I've also tried setting the ouput profile to run makeglossaries-lite.lua, and that has the same result. Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Comment: I've got it working now by running `makeindex.exe` with the arguments `-s "%bm".ist -t "%bm".glg -o "%bm".gls "%bm".glo`. Not sure why that works, but it does.

Comment: `makeindex` alone won't work. `makeglossaries` should work. `makeglossaries-lite` should work. See the `glossaries` documentation. `makeglossaries-lite` doesn't need Perl.

Comment: I just realised I typed `makeindex.bat` in my first comment when I meant `makeglossaries.bat`. Neither `makeglossaries`, nor `makeglossaries-lite` seem to work for me if I add them to the output profile, but `makeindex.exe` works fine. If there's something that's not working properly using only `makeindex.exe`, I can't see it.

Comment: @BZ1 You can look at the documentation for details. On its own, `makeindex` will produce an index rather than a glossary. With those arguments, it produces a glossary. Some functionality is missing, I think, but if you are not using that functionality, you have no reason to care about it ;).

Comment: @BZ1 Check your version number for `glossaries.sty`. If it's below 4.16 then it's likely that `makeglossaries-lite` isn't working because it's not present. It was added to the `glossaries` package in v4.16.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to @cfr's answer, if you still want to use the "noidx" version, you have to set the `sort` key. (In fact, you ought to do that even if you use the other answer, or `makeindex` will view `$\mathrm{x}$` as the sequence of characters `$` `\` `m` `a` `t` `h` `r` `m` `{` `x` `}` `$`
which will throw the alphabetical sorting.)

Modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries


\newglossaryentry{x}
{
name={$\mathrm{x}$},
sort={x},
description={description},
}

\newglossaryentry{y}
{
name={$\mathrm{y}$},
sort={y},
description={description},
}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
\gls{x}
\gls{y}


\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```